# Appendix Section Title without A in Front but Appendix Subsection Titles with A in Front

Tags: appendices, appendix, section-titles

I would like to have the appendix section title without an A in front but subsection title starting with an A (e.g. A1, A2, ...) and also appendix table or figure titles starting with an A. Here is the code I am using. With this code I get an A in front of the Appendix section but if I use \section*{Appendix} I don't get A in front of the subsections.

```
\begin{document}

\documentclass[12pt,letter,notitlepage]{article}
\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{AppendixTables}{Table A.#2} 

\appendix

\section{Appendix}

\captionsetup{labelformat=AppendixTables}
\setcounter{table}{0}

\subsection{Subsection 1}
\subsection{Subsection 2}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

It would have helped if your MWE compiled without errors.

However, try this:

```
% appendixprob.tex  SE 579384

\documentclass[12pt,notitlepage]{article}
%\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{AppendixTables}{Table A.#2} %% causes an error
\usepackage{appendix} %% could be useful but not necessary

\begin{document}

\section{A section}

\appendix
%\begin{appendices}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\hspace{0.5em}} % no number but align with section titles
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\Alph{section}.\arabic{subsection}}
\section{Appendix}

%\captionsetup{labelformat=AppendixTables} %% causes an error
\setcounter{table}{0}

\subsection{Subsection 1}
\subsection{Subsection 2}
%\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

It does what you want regarding the numbering of `\section{Appendix}` but I have no idea if the positioning is what you want. It is up to you to deal with the numbering of floats.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add manually the appendix.

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}

\counterwithin{table}{section}

\newcommand{\singleappendix}[1]{%
  \appendix
  \section*{#1}
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#1}
  \stepcounter{section}
}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{Introduction}

\begin{table}[htp]
\caption{This is a table caption}
\end{table}

\singleappendix{Appendix}

\subsection{Subsection 1}
\subsection{Subsection 2}

\begin{table}[htp]
\caption{This is a table caption}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]